# Node.JS: What is the correct way to handle postdata read errors?

Tags: node.js, http, post, error-handling

If the `ServerRequest` object emits an `error` event, that means that the postdata could not be fully received, most likely due to a network failure. This type of network failure is most likely terminal in both directions, right? So, how should I right my code?

I could say `res.writeHead(400); res.end()`

But is there a smarter way? Perhaps one that just 'does nothing', but will not result in a memory leak / hang. It seems like `request.connection.destroy()` is a good idea, but I am not sure if that is safe.

What would you recommend?

Comment: My guess is you can log a warning if you like although there's not much useful you could ever really do with the information in the log file. Other than that, I would be fairly confident that node itself is going to clean up the associated resources so `connection.destroy` is probably redundant. But I don't have code to prove those hunches.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to do anything. internally, the socket/req/res will be destroyed. it'll be garbage collected eventually.

you don't need to send a response code - the connection is already destroyed so it's not going anywhere.